# How to install gcc 6.4.0 on Cygwin

Tags: gcc, cygwin, gcc6

I have installed cygwin then I ran `setup-x86_64.exe -q -P wget -P gcc-g++` and that installed gcc 5.4.0

But how can I install gcc 6.4.0 on cygwin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Latest test (experimental) version is 6.3.0-2

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin-announce/2017-06/msg00079.html

> All available experimental packages can be selected by pressing the
>   Exp in the top right part of the chooser window. Be warned, however,
>   that the next time you run setup.exe it will try to replace all old or
>   experimental versions with the current version, unless told otherwise.

https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-net.html#setup-packages

Comment: If you want a newer gcc than the experimental download you may build it from source.  The options you will see set in gcc -v must be consulted for guidance.  Java and cilkplus aren't supported.